# Connection string - MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, connection-string, dbcontext

The connection string that I need to use in my MVC application, is not an absolute path and I need to made it up based on DB connection and the environment that the application is publishing. (something like this: [databaseConnection + "_" + environment]).
Can anyone please help me how I can do it in web.config, and also in dbContext (base : (??))
I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a constructor override that you can use to pass in your connection.

```
MyDataDataContext(myConnectionString);
```

For your local machine, just set the string to what you are doing dev testing against.

Going all in, you can extend the [ConfigurationSectionGroup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsectiongroup(v=vs.110).aspx) and create a custom config section in the web config file. That way you could peel off environmental settings based on where the application resides using somekind of tokenization process.